# What is the name of a coupling nut with a cutout?

Tags: electrical, hardware

I'm fixing a lamp and I need a coupling nut to connect the post that contains the electrical wires to a rod that holds the shade. This looks like a normal coupling nut, but with half of the middle cut out to let the electrical wires come through.

What is the name of such a nut?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://www.grandbrass.com/images/hic1b8x8.jpg) ?

Comment: Yes. There's a bit more to the nut, but that's about right.

Comment: @Mazura, I'll remove this pic now that I got an answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have *no* idea why, but an open coupling for a lamp is called a **hickey**...  As in *1/4" IPS Brass Hickey*:

[image]

I've also seen this sold on some sites as an "open cast coupling" or "open cast hickey".

Comment: Yes that is a hickey, old term, a conduit hand bender is another device called to a hickey, don’t know where it originated from but on lower level electrical knowledge tests it is a question asked in Oregon.