# How to exit a threaded lamp rod

Tags: electrical, bulb, lamp

Is there such a thing as a threaded lamp pipe with an opening for the wire to exit into the inside of the glass lamp enclosure? I have a design where the wire enters into the threaded pipe, but then the threaded pipe continues to the outside of the glass enclosure where a "bolt" ends up holding everything together. So if the wire stays inside the rod without exiting, it ends up outside the fixture.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble envisioning what you're after. Maybe edit in a drawing of your design. Overall, though, I think what you're after is a hollow threaded rod, and you shouldn't have too much difficulty finding that.

Comment: A little extra digging and I found this: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/89819/what-is-the-name-of-a-coupling-nut-with-a-cutout

Comment: Yup that's a hickey